# laravel eloquent model casts on save?

Tags: php, laravel, casting, eloquent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting e.g.

`protected $casts = [ 'price' => 'integer', ];` now this will cast when retrieving the value. When saving, I am actually not sure what `$book->price = "20"` will do, e.g. most likely it will save 20.

That is my guess, is it right?

What will `$book->someboolean` with `$casts =[ 'someboolean' -> 'boolean'];`

`$book->someboolean = 'false'; $book->save();`

`$book->someboolean = '0'; $book->save();`

`$book->someboolean = 0; $book->save();`

`$book->someboolean = null; $book->save();`

what will it store?

Comment: Try it out. The answer may even vary depending on database engine.

Comment: @ceejayoz that means eloquent left us alone on that one? because changing the database should not change how the code runs. But as you say, it seems to do exactly that. Fundamentally changes it.

Comment: Well, as an example, `$book->someboolean = null;` will error out in Postgres if the field isn't nullable, but it'll work fine (inserting false) in MySQL. The `$casts` mostly (`json` casts affect how it's saved, IIRC) functions on reads, not writes.

Answer (score 4):

All eloquent does it form the SQL query using fluent methods. The `$casts` property only works when retrieving. For inserting or updating, you should check the database engine and how it casts them.

If you want to force casts with Laravel using eloquent. You can add mutators.

```
public function setSomebooleanAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['someboolean'] = boolval($value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`$casts` does not work on save and update methods. It is call when you get some property from model: `__get()`, `toArray()` or `toJson()`.

**For MySQL:** if you try save "20", database can convert value depending on the column type: if it is integer - 20 will be saved, if boolean - true.

> Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.